# MouseMove event with Right Mouse Button pressed in Safari doesn't work

Tags: javascript, events, safari, mousemove, mousedown

I'm trying to make a game map in HTML with Javascript.
I want the map to move by holding the right mouse button and moving the mouse.
In Firefox and Google Chrome this works correctly, but in Safari it's not working.

Is there any way to make the onMouseMove event work with pressed right mouse button on Safari?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that's not available on Safari. We're developing Ovi Maps 3D and have the same problem - from what I know, Google had the same problem with Google Earth. Safari suppresses all the right mouse button events while it's pressed, so even if you'll block the context menu from showing, you won't get any mouse events.

The only thing I can suggest to you is a fallback for Safari, to allow moving the map while holding some modifier key - Shift or Alt.